# Can I create a Generation 2 VHDX from a physical machine?

Tags: hyper-v

I know that I can use Disk2VHD or Hyper-V Manager to create a VHDX from a physical drive of a server.

My Problem is, I can only create VHDX that can only be booted by Generation 1 Virtual Machines in Hyper-V.

Is there a way to create a VHDX from a physical drive that is able to use Generation 2 in Hyper V?

The Server I will create the VHDX from is a HP ProLiant DL320 G5 Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Have you tried Convert-VMGeneration? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Convert-VMGeneration-81ddafa2/view/Discussions/2 and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @GregAskew sounds very promising. I will try and come back to you in a few days